# Calculation of Standard Error (SE) in scipy's implementation of one sample t-test?

Tags: python, t-test

I've implemented a simple one sample t-test in python:

```
import numpy as np
from math import sqrt
from scipy.stats import t, ttest_1samp

def one_sample_ttest(sample, global_mean, alpha=0.05):
    n = sample.size
    std = np.std(sample)
    mean = np.mean(sample)
    serr = std / sqrt(n)
    tscore = (mean - global_mean) / serr
    pval = (t.sf(x=tscore, df=n-1)) * 2  # alternatively = (1 - t.cdf(x=tstat, df=n-1)) * 2

    return tscore, pval
```

However, when comparing the computed t-score with [`ttest_1samp` from `scipy.stats` module](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.ttest_1samp.html), I'm getting a different result:

```
data = np.array([5.473, 2.967, 5.337, -1.054])

print(one_sample_ttest(data, 0.0)[0])
print(ttest_1samp(data, 0.0).statistic)

######################
2.4094767021440173
2.08666803388347
```

Through trial-and-error, I've found this is likely caused by the calculation of the standard error in the denominator of the test formula:

$$
t=\frac{\bar{x} - \mu_0}{\frac{s}{\sqrt{n}}}
$$

which becomes (using the number of DoF instead of sample size):

$$
t=\frac{\bar{x} - \mu_0}{\frac{s}{\sqrt{n-1}}}
$$

Is there a particular reason for this? What are the practical implications?